# Printing entire array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, io

I have a simple 2D array:

```
int[,] m = { {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0} };
```

How can I print this out onto a text file or something? I want to print the entire *array* onto a file, not just the contents. For example, I don't want a bunch of zeroes all in a row: I want to see the

```
{{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0} };
```

in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just iterate over it and produce the output. Something like

```
static string ArrayToString<T>(T[,] array)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("{");

    for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        if (i != 0) builder.Append(",");
        builder.Append("{");

        for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            if (j != 0) builder.Append(",");
            builder.Append(array[i, j]);
        }

        builder.Append("}");
    }

    builder.Append("}");

    return builder.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no standard way to get those `{` brackets, you have to put them through the code while iterating through your array and writing them to the file